# Code from my java files no longer appear in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

The code from my java files no longer appear in Eclipse
(Juno R1) and it was there last week.  The code is in 
the file and the classes appear in the Projects, Packages, 
Types, & Members panels in Eclipse, so I know it's 
reading the java files, but neither file appears in 
the code panel.
Does anyone know how to force the code to appear
in the code panel?  The ShowView item on the Window
menu has a view for everything except code.

Comment: :As far as I understood your problem ,you may have accidently changed your workspace or whatever.Eclipse provides the feature of importing projects.So you can import projects from your previous workspace and it will again start appearing in project explorer.

Comment: Is Eclipse in the Java perspective?

Answer (score 2):

If you can see your project files but the content of the files are wrong, try updating the files, by *right clicking the project note* and selecting *Refresh*, this will force eclipse to reload all files form you filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're in the correct workspace and I'm going to assume you just upgraded to Juno so you're going to have to import your existing projects I'm pretty sure. Right click on the list window, click import then I think import existing projects or something like that is under the general tab. To be honest I started using nano in the terminal and its been a while since I've used Eclipse but I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: Wow, those were some quick replies.  
I just installed Eclipse last month and I only have one workspace.  
The two projects are just simple samples and were created in this 
version of Eclipse and the current workspace.  I assume something 
in the workspace has changed but I don't know how to verify that or 
how to correct it.  Refresh and reloading the workspace didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried to import the projects? It sounds like they're no longer in the current workspace so I'd give that a try.

Comment: And in the worst case scenario, you said you could see the see files, right? So open up the sourcefiles of the two projects create a new project in Eclipse create some classes and copy and paste away. If you need anymore help I'm going to need a little bit more information about the system you're running but I'm pretty sure  if you import the projects into the Eclipse workspace that will solve your problem. And if you do need more help you're probably better off contacting eclipse. I've never needed to but Im sure they have some sor t of coustomer support set up

Comment: I can see the files, both in a text editor and in the types panel in Eclipse.  I closed all projects then tried to import and got an error, so I created a new project, which still didn't show the code, so I closed and imported that and still didn't see the code.  I'm thinking, there has to be a button somewhere that pops up the code panel.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.   When I clicked OpenFile from the File menu, the java file appeared in Eclipse.  I didn't do that before because I didn't think Eclipse would understand that that file is the SRC file referenced above.   I'll have to experiment some more to see if that really works.